# PHP query for updating table with same session_id

Tags: php, mysql, session-variables

I used `session_id` as the ID column in my db.There is one more column named Sections where added the whole `xml`. The `xml` contains section names and the amount of time user spent there. I want to update the Sections column for same session_ids. How can I do that? Right now it adds a new row for every record. Here is my php code

```
$id=$_SESSION["id"];
$totaltime=$_POST['total'];
$HomeTime=$_POST['home'];
$ProductTime=$_POST['products'];
$ProcessTime=$_POST['process'];
$DevTime=$_POST['dev'];
$ContactTime=$_POST['contact'];


$xmlObject = <<<XML
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<item>
    <section>
        <name>Home</name>
        <time>$HomeTime</time>
    </section>  
    <section>
        <name>Product</name>
        <time>$ProductTime</time>
    </section>
    <section>
        <name>Process</name>
        <time>$ProcessTime</time>
    </section>  
    <section>
        <name>Development</name>
        <time>$DevTime</time>
    </section>
    <section>
        <name>Contact</name>
        <time>$ContactTime</time>
    </section>
    </item>
XML;



    $sql = "INSERT INTO user_time (ID, Sections) VALUES ('$id', '$xmlObject')";

    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        echo "New record created successfully";
    } else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
    }
```

Comment: If ID is a primary key or a unique key, you can just use REPLACE INTO instead of INSERT INTO.

Comment: It contains time and I want to add to the previous values. So replacing won't work

Comment: Means, you want update the existing XML data by adding new time data. right?

Comment: yes right, for same sessions there will be only one row

Comment: If you intend to update the row based on the same id but the content of the `Sections` has to be changed based on the time in the XML content, you have to first retrieve the previous `Sections` contents form the SQL, replace the time or whatever data you want to, then further update it based on the id

Answer (score 0):

First fetch existing XML data from db using the session id it exists, and store to variable `$xmlFromDB` and proceed with following steps. Otherwise insert to db.

```
if(session id exisits in db){
    //Fetch the table row or corresponding session id.
    //Extract times from XML using this code.

    $arr = [];
    $times = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlFromDB);
    foreach($times->section as $sec){
        $arr[$sec->name.""] = $sec->time;
    }
    extract($arr);

    //This will add previous value to new value.
    $HomeTime += $Home;
    $ProductTime += $Product;
    $ProcessTime += $Process;
    $DevTime += $Development;
    $ContactTime += $Contact;
}

//Now generate xml using your method.

$xmlObject = <<<XML
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
    <item>
        <section>
            <name>Home</name>
            <time>$HomeTime</time>
        </section>  
        <section>
            <name>Product</name>
            <time>$ProductTime</time>
        </section>
        <section>
            <name>Process</name>
            <time>$ProcessTime</time>
        </section>  
        <section>
            <name>Development</name>
            <time>$DevTime</time>
        </section>
        <section>
            <name>Contact</name>
            <time>$ContactTime</time>
        </section>
        </item>
XML;

if(session id exists){
    //Then update the same row using the UPDATE  query.
    $sql = "UPDATE user_time SET Sections = '$xmlObject' where = '$id'";
}else{
    $sql = "INSERT INTO user_time (ID, Sections) VALUES ('$id', '$xmlObject')";
}

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}
```