# I am Using $_SESSION('ID') , To UPDATE into table not working and no error through php page

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to update data using the SESSION ID so the email, verification_status, verification_id will be inserted those who currently login on that ID. To simplify i a creating a voting system, once they input their acct number, they will be redirected to email verification link when they input they're email it will be inserted to their database. but still on the same row of database.

```
<?php
session_start();
require('../classes/StudentLogin.php');
require('../config/db.php');

$msg="";
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

$email=$_POST['email'];


$check=mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query($db,"select * from voters where email='$email'"));

if($check>0){
    $msg="Email id already present";
}else{
    $verification_id=rand(111111111,999999999);

  $id=mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_SESSION['ID']);


    mysqli_query($db,"UPDATE voters WHERE 
   id=$id SET(email,verification_status,verification_id) 
   values($email',0,'$verification_id')");

    $msg="We've just sent a verification link to <strong>$email</strong>. Please check your inbox and 
    click on the link to get started. If you can't find this email (which could be due to spam 
    filters), just request a new one here.";

    $mailHtml="Please confirm your account registration by clicking the button or link below: <a 
    href='http://127.0.0.1/PHPEmailVerification/check.php? 
    id=$verification_id'>http://127.0.0.1/PHPEmailVerification/check.php?id=$verification_id</a>";

    smtp_mailer($email,'Account Verification',$mailHtml);



     }
     }
```

Comment: You can't use `WHERE` in `INSERT`. `iNSERT` is for creating new rows, `WHERE` is for selecting existing rows.

Comment: Use `UPDATE` if you want to modify existing rows, not `INSERT`.

Comment: Or maybe what you want is `INSERT INTO voters ... SELECT ... WHERE id = '$id'`

Comment: I tried to use update but it still doesn't work and no error result im stuck

Comment: you shouldn't change to update because you need INSERT.

Comment: yes you're right is there any other way of inserting it using for example REPLACE INTO, because what i am trying to do is i have a database of voters and it has a id,name,stud_id this all have values except of email, verification_status , verification_id, this will have a value when the user input they're email. Simply i just want to pull up the row of my table and update it

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53493896/php-query-for-updating-table-with-same-session-id  this is exactly what i want to happen though but maybe i can use replace into ?

Answer (score 0):

It's not totally clear what you're trying to do, but I think `id` should be one of the columns you're inserting, you don't use `WHERE`.

```
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($db, "insert into voters (id,email,verification_status,verification_id) 
   values(?, ?, 0, ?)");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sss", $id, $email, $verification_id);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
```

I've also recoded it to use a prepared statement instead of substituting variables. Then you don't need to use `mysqli_real_escape_string()` (which you forgot to use for `$email`).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53493896/php-query-for-updating-table-with-same-session-id what i am trying to do is same as this, But thank you for your answer barmar

Answer (score -1):

Thank you for your help guys I solved it :)

this is my code that i've come up

```
    <?php
     session_start();
    require('../classes/StudentLogin.php');
    require('../config/db.php');

    $msg="";
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    $email=$_POST['email'];


   $check=mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query($db,"select * from voters where 
   email='$email'"));

   if($check>0){
    $msg="Email id already present";
    }else{
    $verification_id=rand(111111111,999999999);

    $id=mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_SESSION['ID']);


    mysqli_query($db,"UPDATE voters SET email = '$email', verification_id = 
   '$verification_id', verification_status = '0' WHERE id = '$id'");

    $msg="We've just sent a verification link to <strong>$email</strong>. Please check 
    your inbox and click on the link to get started. If you can't find this email 
    (which could be due to spam filters), just request a new one here.";

    $mailHtml="Please confirm your account registration by clicking the button or link 
    below: <a href='http://127.0.0.1/PHPEmailVerification/check.php? 
    id=$verification_id'>http://127.0.0.1/PHPEmailVerification/check.php? 
    id=$verification_id</a>";

    smtp_mailer($email,'Account Verification',$mailHtml);



    }
    }
```